# Blazor - A frame of type 'Element' was left unclosed. Do not use try/catch inside rendering logic, because partial output cannot be undone

Tags: c#, html, html-table, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am having a mind-stumping issue. I am making an HTML table in Blazor from multiple queries, and I want them displayed side by side in a table. It works, unless I select a year before 2018 in my query, and it is driving me insane.

The first query is of the most recent year and has certain accounts numbers. the other tables have less accounts because they didn't exist in those years. So I have complicated logic to have the accounts align in my table. For example, if query one has accounts 1, 2, 3 and query 2 has accounts 1, 3, the query 2 portion of the table will display data in rows 1 and 3. I have a  box that allows you to pick a year, so I began testing years. 2018-2021 work perfectly, but when I try 2017 or before, I get an unclosed Element error. The database contains data on 2017 and several years before, so it's not a null query.

What confuses me is that I am just changing the C# variable 'year2' and it has no bearing on the HTML side of things. I am totally stumped and I don't have the slightest idea why this doesn't work. I am going to have to go back to the drawing board most likely, but I wanted to see if anyone here had a clue what to do. This feels like a longshot, but I'll post the table below

```
<table Height="200" class="table">
        <thead class="sticky-top">
            <tr>
                <th>GL</th>
                <th>Acount</th>
                <th>22 YTD</th>
                <th>Percentage</th>
                <th>@year2 YTD</th>
                <th>Percentage</th>
                <th>@year3.ToString() YTD</th>
                <th>Percentage</th>
                <th>@year4.ToString() YTD</th>
                <th>Percentage</th>
                <th>@year5.ToString() YTD</th>
                <th>Percentage</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           @for(int i = 0; i < statements.Count; i++)
           {
                int index = i;
                <tr>
                    <td>@statements[i].Account</td>
                    <td>@statements[i].GL</td>
                    <td>@statements[i].amount</td>
                    <td>@(Math.Round(100*statements[i].amount/firstTotal,2))%</td>
                    @try{
                        @if (statements2[i - indexother12].GL == statements[i].GL)
                        {
                            
                            <td>@statements2[i - indexother12].amount</td>
                            <td>@(Math.Round(100 * statements2[i - indexother12].amount / firstTotal, 2))%</td>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            indexother12++;
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        indexother12++;
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    }
                    @try{
                        @if (statements3[i-indexother2].GL == statements[i].GL)
                        {
                            @*<td>@statements2[otherIndex].Account</td>
                             <td>@statements2[otherIndex].GL</td>*@
                            <td>@statements3[i-indexother2].amount</td>
                            <td>@(Math.Round(100 * statements3[i - indexother2].amount / firstTotal, 2))%</td>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            indexother2++;
                            @*<td></td>
                            <td></td>*@
                            <td>Debug1</td>
                            <td>Debug1</td>
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        indexother2++;
                        <td>Debug2</td>
                        <td>Debug2</td>
                    }
    
                </tr>
           }
            <tr style="font-weight:bold">
                <td>TOTAL REVENUE</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>@firstTotal</td>
                <td>100%</td>
                <td>@secondTotal</td>
                <td>100%</td>
                <td>@thirdTotal</td>
                <td>100%</td>
            </tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < dcofrev.Count; i++) // Costs of Revenue
            {
                int index = i;
                Console.WriteLine(dcofrev2.Count + " " + (indexother1).ToString() + " Made It Here " + i);
                <tr>
                    <td>@dcofrev[i].Account</td>
                    <td>@dcofrev[i].GL</td>
                    <td>@dcofrev[i].amount</td>
                    <td>@(Math.Round(100 * dcofrev[i].amount / firstTotalCost, 2))%</td>  
                    @try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Is it trying?");
                            if (dcofrev2[i - indexother1].GL == dcofrev[i].GL)
                            {
                                <td>@dcofrev2[i-indexother1].amount</td>
                                <td>@(Math.Round(100 * dcofrev2[i - indexother1].amount / secondTotalCost, 2))%</td>
                                Console.WriteLine(dcofrev[i].GL + " - " + dcofrev2[i - indexother1].GL + " And Here " + i);
                            }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Is it elsing?");
                            indexother1++;
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        }
                        
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" Catching Here " + i);
                        indexother1++;
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    }
                    @try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Getting here???");
                        if (dcofrev3[i - indexother2].GL == dcofrev[i].GL)
                        {
                            <td>@dcofrev3[i-indexother2].amount</td>
                            <td>@(Math.Round(100 * dcofrev2[i - indexother2].amount / thirdTotalCost, 2))%</td>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            indexother2++;
                            @*<td></td>
                            <td></td>*@
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        indexother2++;
                        @*<td></td>
                        <td></td>*@
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
            <tr style="font-weight:bold">
                <td>TOTAL COST OF REVENUE</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>@firstTotalCost</td>
                <td>100%</td>
                <td>@secondTotalCost</td>
                <td>100%</td>
                <td>@thirdTotalCost</td>
                <td>100%</td>
                <td>@fourthTotalCost</td>
                <td>100%</td>
                <td>@fifthTotalCost</td>
                <td>100%</td>
            </tr>
    
        </tbody>
    
    </table>
```

Comment: I understand thew "try catch" warning, but I wonder why it works with a certain set of variable and seemingly randomly not when it goes below 18. I think I may just make one large query that handles this for me, that should be simpler and less of a headache. The logic was almost beginning to be hard to follow in that table.

Comment: I concur with @HH on this.  Get both the data and the logic into a view service.  Think only UI logic (do I display or hide some data, do I disable/enable a button) in the component.  Everything to do with data in the view service.  `Try` is a no-no in Razor Logic.  Your code gets compiled into a C# class with RenderTreeBuilder methods replacing your markup.  It's the equivalent of assembler for the UI, miss a pop after a push and it all goes pear shaped!

Comment: Instead of try catch, you can use the `ErrorBoundary` component. But I highly suggest to generate the 3 tables in your ViewModel and just print out it's values. It's never a good idea to have business logic inside your front-end code.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. The problem is raised due to wrongly placed 'tr' or 'td' tag for **Total** row inside the table tag.

**Example with issue:**

```
    <TableComponent @ref="Table" TTableItem="your_model" apiUrl="your_api_url">
    <CustomRow TTableItem="your_model" IsActiveForItem="@(x => x.Type == "T")">            
            @foreach (CustomColumnModel<your_model> customColumn in GetCustomColumns())
            {
                <tr>
                <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
                    @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customColumn.sectionName)) // section name either normal or total column
                    {
                        <td><strong></strong></td>
                    }
                    else if (customColumn.sectionName.Equals("total", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        <td @key="customColumn.column"
                            style="@(customColumn.column?.GetStyle() ?? string.Empty)"
                            class="@(Table.TdPadding) @(customColumn.column?.Class ?? string.Empty)">
                            <strong>@customColumn.column?.Render(context)</strong>
                        </td>
                    }    
                </tr>
            }
    </CustomRow>
</TableComponent>
```

**Correct example:**

```
<TableComponent @ref="Table" TTableItem="your_model" apiUrl="your_api_url">
    <CustomRow TTableItem="your_model" IsActiveForItem="@(x => x.Type == "T")">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
            @foreach (CustomColumnModel<your_model> customColumn in GetCustomColumns())
            {
                @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customColumn.sectionName)) // section name either normal or total column
                {
                    <td><strong></strong></td>
                }
                else if (customColumn.sectionName.Equals("total", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    <td @key="customColumn.column"
                        style="@(customColumn.column?.GetStyle() ?? string.Empty)"
                        class="@(Table.TdPadding) @(customColumn.column?.Class ?? string.Empty)">
                        <strong>@customColumn.column?.Render(context)</strong>
                    </td>
                }
            }
        </tr>
    </CustomRow>
</TableComponent>
```

[BlazorTable](https://github.com/IvanJosipovic/BlazorTable) is used in this example. You can find its demo [here](https://blazortable.netlify.app/).